# How to clean chrome in-memory cache?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing an extension in chrome and I'm trying to perform an action each time a user searches in Google. Currently I'm using [chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) onBeforeRequest listener. It works perfectly most of the cases but some of the requests are done through the cache and doesn't perform any call. I've found this in the API documentation about [caching](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html#caching):

> Chrome employs two caches — an on-disk cache and a very fast in-memory cache. The lifetime of an in-memory cache is attached to the lifetime of a render process, which roughly corresponds to a tab. Requests that are answered from the in-memory cache are invisible to the web request API. If a request handler changes its behavior (for example, the behavior according to which requests are blocked), a simple page refresh might not respect this changed behavior. To make sure the behavior change goes through, call **handlerBehaviorChanged()** to flush the in-memory cache. But don't do it often; flushing the cache is a very expensive operation. You don't need to call **handlerBehaviorChanged()** after registering or unregistering an event listener.

I've tried using the handlerBehaviorChanged() method to empty the in-memory cache, but there was no difference. Although it's not recommended I've even tried to call it after every request.

This is my code:

```
chrome.webRequest.MAX_HANDLER_BEHAVIOR_CHANGED_CALLS_PER_10_MINUTES = 1000;
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(function (details) {
    //perform action
    chrome.webRequest.handlerBehaviorChanged();
} {
    urls: ["*://*.google.com/*"]
});
```

Is there any way to empty/disable this in-memory cache from the extension?

Comment: I'm fairly confident `MAX_HANDLER_BEHAVIOR_CHANGED_CALLS_PER_10_MINUTES` is not a settable value; it is there for informational purposes only. It's available so Chrome can tell you how often you are allowed to flush the cache, not so you can tell Chrome how often you want to.

Comment: Can you give some more Context? I dont understand which call come out of the cache. I Tested, If i use the goolge website an enter in the searchbox "Test" i can see all request, when i than click "Search", i also see an request, i only dont see a request, when i click various times on the search button without changing the searchfield, but i dont assume you mean this.

Comment: @winner_joiner A simple way to use the cache is to search "What if" and then click down-arroy key to show the suggestions and switch between them many times. Only the first times the requests are done.

Comment: @apsillers I've tried it with and without setting a value to `MAX_HANDLER_BEHAVIOR_CHANGED_CALLS_PER_10_MINUTES`, and there's no diference so I supose you're right.

Comment: @Kaizo I sorry i can reproduce or better said undertand/see the problem. When i select other entries in the dropdown there is always a (at least one) get-request being send and it returns an 204 or 200 HTTP Status. i'm not excatly sure what want to achieve(the final goal) but perhapse, this caching is some kind of Javascript-Google-Magic to make the website seem to perform faster(btw. I am using chrome 27+ on Windows)

Comment: @winner_joiner I'm using Chrome 28.0 on Ubuntu 13.04. Google performs many kind of requests, but the search ones are those like this one: `https://www.google.com/search?q=what%20if%20lyrics%20coldplay(...)`. Maybe you are capturing any other request that is performed.

Comment: Hi wanted to ask, did you find a solution? if so could you share it with us? Thx

Comment: No, I couldn't find a solution for the cache problem, so I searched a solution to my specific problem: perform action when google searches (or had searched). It is worst, because  the user first waits for google search and then for my action. Here is the solution: [how-to-know-when-google-searches](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163305/how-to-know-when-google-searches)

Answer (score 1):

I **asume** the "Caching" is performed by the Google-Website with some crazy JavaScript in Objects, Arrays,... so emptying the browser in Memory-Cache won't help.

My first thought was that the data was Stored in the sessionStorage (due to the fact that the Values had the search-term in them [here I searched for test] and are updated/created on every request/change of the selected "search-word"

[image])

*I tried clearing the Sessionstorage (even periodicaly), but it didn't really change the "not"-loading, further more the storage was recreated and even without the storage, the different results were displayed.*

Due to this Information and the fact that I can't check several 1000 lines of minfied JavaScript Code, I just can asume that the website does the caching of the requests. I hope this Information can point you in the right direction.