# How to know when google searches?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a chrome extension and I need to know when is google searching to perform an action on each search.

I've tried to listen the requests with [chrome.webRequest](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest.html) but the cached requests aren't captured.

Evernote extension searches in my notes each time I search in Google, even if the request is cached. How are they doing it or how to make something similar?

Comment: What about a content script injected into all of the google homepages? Sounds ugly but may work...

Comment: Thanks for the answer @CamiloMartin . I alredy have a content script, but it won't tell me when a search is performed because google is using Ajax.

Comment: With the content script i can find what is searching, but not when.

Comment: What about analyzing the search results instead of the webrequest? You could periodically look at the page for search results and analyze the content. Kind of slow and hacky, but I'm not sure what else you would do if webRequest doesn't provide you with what you need.

Comment: @JudeOsborn What i'm trying now is look at the search field and the URL in an interval for any changes and then perform the action. But it doesn't feel as smooth as Evernote. I'll try monitoring the results, but for diferent searches you may get same results.

Comment: Another idea - `$(window).on('hashchange', fun);` (on the content script).

Comment: @CamiloMartin That was close, but not enough. With Google Instant search or with the search suggestions the hash is updated some seconds after the searches are done.

Comment: @Kaizo Really? Wow, that's unexpected. Maybe reverse-engineering some of how search works, you could replace some function it calls with `someApi.oldFunction = function() { yourCode(); oldFunction(); }`, but it kinda sucks. Or monitor when some DOM element gets new content? Kinda sucks too...

Comment: Yes @CamiloMartin, really unexpected. You can try it with `window.setInterval(function(){console.log(location.hash.match(/q=(.*?)(?=&)/)[1])}, 200)` and switching between the suggested searches. I'll die reverse-engineering the google ofuscated code, but it's an option. I'll try it monitoring, but many DOM elements are deleted each search. Hope to find the correct element ;).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a post on the subject [http://isgeek.eu/google-chrome-extension-google-search](http://isgeek.eu/?p=54)

The trick is to use

```
document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){
```

to listen to each change on the google search page.

Comment: It fires many times the event for each search. I've tryied with this: `document.addEventListener("DOMSubtreeModified", function(event){console.log(document.getElementById('gs_taif0').value||document.getElementById('gbqfq').value)});` and it fires the event for every item is added to the dom. Am I doing it wrong? Is there a way to make it fire one event and not 15?

Comment: It is explained on the website. A way to only listen to the first of the 15 "DOMSubtreeModification" is to add a little DIV in the google result main DIV. If the user makes a new search, then the div will be erased by google.

Comment: It seams to work well. This is more or less what @CamiloMartin suggested to do, but monitoring all the DOM. Thanks.