# Modifying the Referer request header through a Google Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, underscore.js

I've got the following code which attempts to ensure that a Referer header is set when issuing requests:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(function (info) {
    var refererRequestHeader = _.find(info.requestHeaders, function (requestHeader) {
        return requestHeader.name === 'Referer';
    });

    var refererUrl = info.url.substring(0, info.url.indexOf('/embed/'));

    if (_.isUndefined(refererRequestHeader)) {
        info.requestHeaders.push({
            name: 'Referer',
            value: refererUrl
        });
    } else {
        refererRequestHeader.value = refererUrl;
    }   

    return { requestHeaders: info.requestHeaders };
}, {
    //  Match on my specific iframe or else else this logic can leak into outside webpages and corrupt other YouTube embeds.
    urls: ['*://*.youtube.com/embed/?enablejsapi=1&origin=chrome-extension:\\\\jbnkffmindojffecdhbbmekbmkkfpmjd']
},
    ['blocking', 'requestHeaders']
);
```

This code works great 99% of the time. However, on some PCs, it fails. I am attempting to investigate why this is happening, but I don't have very many leads to go on.

My questions are:

- Does this code look appropriate for what it is attempting to achieve? I attempt to find an existing Referer requestHeader. If found, I set the header's value to the given URL. If the header is not found, I push it.
- I've done some reading on the "handlerBehaviorChanged" method exposed through chrome.webRequest.handlerBehaviorChanged, but I'm still unsure if this is something which could resolve my issue. I found this post: [How to clean chrome in-memory cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17135131/how-to-clean-chrome-in-memory-cache) which hints at intermittent errors with chrome.webRequest... however, I didn't see anything conclusive. Would it be prudent to call handleBehaviorChanged after setting my listener?
- What other options might I have for debugging this issue? Has anyone experienced intermittent failures in related scenarios?

Comment: What is `_` in this code?

Comment: It is the underscoreJS library as denoted in my tags.

Comment: Other extensions making conflicting changes?

Comment: I was speaking to a user who installed the extension a few moments beforehand. He hadn't installed anything else afterward and, according to documentation, conflict resolution favors the most recently installed extension. So, I'm not sure that's the case.

Comment: Does this really work? Shouldn't you use `chrome-extension://` instead of `chrome-extension:\\\\`? What happens when your code "fails"?

Comment: Oh shit. I wonder if that was causing odd issues. I was bypassing YouTube's iFrame API due to this bug: https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=5788 but I got my slashes backwards. So, I had the slashes backwards in two spots which was causing inject to be successful, but definitely undefined behavior. I will see if that resolves anything.

Comment: @Robw -- Interestingly enough. The YouTube iFrame API does NOT fire onReady when I use chrome-extension//, but it DOES fire successfully when I use chrome-extension\\\\. So, there is some reasoning to the madness.